# Is is possible to pass a selector as a function parameter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, selector

I am trying to develop a kind of slideshow to an specifi application. I am having some problems with the incremetation of the div to be shown.
I need to pass the selector with its position, and so increment its position.

Check the code of what I need to do:

HTML:

```
    <div name="div-default" class="title-result">
        <?php
            echo "$name";
        ?>
    </div>
    <div name="div01" id="div01" class="title-result">
        <?php
            echo "Seu número de Personalidade é: $numerologia[0]";
        ?>
    </div>
    <div name="div02" class="title-result">
        <?php
            echo "Seu número de Destino é: $numerologia[1]";
        ?>
    </div>
    <div name="div03" class="title-result">
        <?php
            echo "Seu número de Lição de Vida é: $numerologia[2]";
        ?>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button onclick="mudarDivNext([name ^= div0]:nth-child(SEND_ITS_POSITION_HERE))" id="next" class="change-div"></button>
     </div>
```

CSS:

```
 //here i define that the first div is visible, and the next ones invisible
    div[name ^= div0]:nth-child(2){
        display: inherit;
    }

    div[name ^= div0]{
        display: none;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
//This script already works for a fix position (from 2 for 3, for example) - need to make it work for all the divs.
function mudarDivNext(){
    var n = 2;
    $("[name ^= div0]:nth-child("+n+")").css("display", "none");
    $("[name ^= div0]:nth-child("+(n+1)+")").css("display", "inherit");
}
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, did you try it?

Comment: Yes I did.. It didn't work here. I can't figure out how to send the number of my div position ([name ^= div0]:nth-child(2);[name ^= div0]:nth-child(3); [name ^= div0]:nth-child(4))...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you just add a class to the visible element and allow jQuery to choose the next element to get the class when you click:

```
<div name="div-default" class="title-result active">
        <?php
            echo "$name";
        ?>
    </div>



<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
                (function ($) { 

            $('#next').on('click',function(){

                $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');


            });

        })(jQuery);
    });
</script>
```

then add css to only show the div with the 'active' class.

```
<style>
.title-result{display:none;}
.title-result.active{display:block;/*or whatever*/}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things, don't forget about the quotes when you are using inline function calls, and use string concatenation to send the parameter:

```
mudarDivNext("[name ^= div0]:nth-child(" + variable + ")")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I define the value of a variable in my HTML code? :( I need to get the position of my div, which i coudn't do yet.

Comment: Hmm...position based on what? I also believe you should throw this into it's own handler for the button, that way you can use an instance of `this` to track down the div's index and use that.